# Setting delegate of another class with screen view to self

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I'm fairly new at iOS programming. I have this setup:

`ViewController` view on IB, with class `ViewController`

`SecondController` view on IB, with class `secondController`

I have protocol:

```
protocol SecondControllerDelegate {
    func getSomething() -> String
}
```

and I have delegate variable on SecondController:

```
class secondController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: SecondControllerDelegate?
    @IBOutlet weak var labelStatus: UILabel!

    override func ViewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        labelStatus.text = delegate?.getSomething()
    }

    func try () {
        labelStatus.text = "testing"
    }
}
```

Now, according to the hints everywhere, in order so I can call `delegate?.getSomething()` at `SecondController.buttonTouch()`, I need to set like this on viewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SecondControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad () {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SecondController.delegate = self
    }
    func doSomething () -> String {
        return "testing"
    }
}
```

But this generates error `'SecondController.type' does not have a member named 'delegate'`.

Some other websites say:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SecondControllerDelegate {
    var secondController = SecondController()
    override func viewDidLoad () {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        secondController.delegate = self
    }
    func doSomething () -> String {
        return "testing"
    }
}
```

With this, there are no error. But if I do something on the second screen that should call the delegate, it doesn't call the delegate, like the SecondController is two different objects (one is created by StoryBoard, one is created manually within the ViewController), i.e. the `labelStatus` that should have changed to "testing", doesn't change at all. But it changes if function `try()` is called. How am I supposed to do this?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I used NavigationController, and segue to transition from first screen to second screen.

Comment: By the way, in your example, you have a delegate protocol in which `SecondViewController` calls `doSomething` to request information from `ViewController`. That would be very uncommon. Usually if a view controller wanted to pass something on to the next view controller, it would just do that when it was transitioning to that next scene (e.g. in `prepareForSegue` of the first view controller). You use the delegate protocol pattern when the second view controller wants to provide some data to the first view controller, not the other way around.

Comment: Yes, it's uncommon. I just wanted to find a test case where I can show where the problem is. Turns out I have to set the delegate on prepareForSegue, that's what I need to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you try to learn how to build a delegate in Swift, I have written you a plain delegate example below

```
protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    func didReceiveInformationFromSecondViewcontroller (information: String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, SecondViewControllerDelegate {

    func openSecondViewController () {
        if let secondViewControllerInstance: SecondViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController {
            secondViewControllerInstance.delegate = self
            navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewControllerInstance, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func didReceiveInformationFromSecondViewcontroller(information: String) {
        ////Here you get the information, after sendInfoToViewController() has been executed
    }

}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?

    func sendInfoToViewController () {
        delegate?.didReceiveInformationFromSecondViewcontroller("This ist the information")
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Following the same thing in using Storyboard Segues

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let secondViewControllerInstance: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
            secondViewControllerInstance.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does that make sense to you? Or any other problems with that?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use NavigationController, and segue to transition from first screen to second screen. I don't know if this matters or not.

Comment: Oh I see, let me try the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` function. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't matter for the delegate pattern, but it matters on how to "open" the second ViewController... I will write you an update

Comment: Yes Rob, thanks... I will give him the example with prepareForSegue as an update

Comment: instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier is no function, it is the instance of your SecondViewController which will be shown on the screen mate :-)

Comment: Yes, the updated one works! I don't know it would be much simpler because of segue, than if I must access the storyboard itself. Thank you for your help! :)